# Delete Lines from a text file

Tags: java

I have a text file that contains 50 million e-mails, and I want to create a program that helps me delete lines from this file.

The program asks me to enter a string: `@gmail.com`. Then I want to delete all of the lines that contain the string `@gmail.com`.

Comment: What have you tried? We won't do your homework for you, if that's what you were hoping for :)

Comment: Does it have to be in Java? This can be achieved very easily using Standard UNIX command line tools. e.g. `grep -v "@gmail\.com" file`

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you.

Edit: Code removed. Text explains every step of the way.

Create a method removeLineFromFile that takes two parameters, the first parameter is the file to remove from and the second parameter is the content of the line to remove.

A tempfile is created and written to, except for the content that matches the second parameter.

Hint: Use a bufferReader to read the file and you could use a PrintWriter or FileWriter to write to the temp file.

This way very large files can be handled without demanding so much internal memory. The original file is then deleted and the tempfile is renamed to the original filename.

Comment: You shouldn't give fully coded answers to a question marked "homework"

Comment: Didn't see the tag. Not sure if I should remove it now..

Comment: Modify the code into psudocode =D

Comment: Unless of course you introduced some subtle errors for the student to catch and correct... (or fail the assignment if s/he doesn't)  :-)

Comment: Removed the code. Will be more careful next time. Was browsing for #java tags and didn't realize this one also had #homework. Thanks ;)

Comment: I´m sorry but it´s not a Homework .. i just need it for my self to Specify my Mail list !

Comment: Well you did a the #homework tag to your question. Is there anything you don't understand in my explanation and need help with?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers, Well This is not a Homework ... I Just need it for my self ! I know how to program in Pascal and I know that It could do it but the problem that I Have a 64 bits computer so neither Turbo pascal nor Borland Pascal will work for me but I have Eclipse in my Computer and I looked in the Internet and nearest code to my case is this:

http://pastebin.com/fyic6HqY

Answer (score 2):

General instructions:

- Open a `Scanner` of a `BufferedReader` of a `FileReader` of your file.
- Open a `BufferedWriter` of a `FileWriter` of a new file.
- For each line in the `Scanner`:

  - If line string does not contain your string

    - Write line to writer
- Close all closables.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers, Well This is not a Homework ... I Just need it for my self ! I know how to program in Pascal and I know that It could do it but the problem that I Have a 64 bits computer so neither Turbo pascal nor Borland Pascal will work for me but I have Eclipse in my Computer and I looked in the Internet and nearest code to my case is this:

http://pastebin.com/fyic6HqY

Answer (score 1):

```
IO readline while(....){
if(str.indexof("@gmail")){
ioHelp.deleteline(str)
}}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't do but good, the trick here is how do you delete a line in a file. As others have said you can't, you can copy copy the file without the offending lines.

Comment: This is my code : http://pastebin.com/fyic6HqY Could you help me please where to put ! and what exactely should I put !? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for all your answers, Well This is not a Homework ... I Just need it for my self ! I know how to program in Pascal and I know that It could do it but the problem that I Have a 64 bits computer so neither Turbo pascal nor Borland Pascal will work for me but I have Eclipse in my Computer and I looked in the Internet and nearest code to my case is this:

http://pastebin.com/fyic6HqY

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all your answers, Well This is not a Homework ... I Just need it for my self ! I know how to program in Pascal and I know that It could do it but the problem that I Have a 64 bits computer so neither Turbo pascal nor Borland Pascal will work for me but I have Eclipse in my Computer and I looked in the Internet and nearest code to my case is this:

http://pastebin.com/fyic6HqY